# Wrong solution for validity of BST

Tags: tree, breadth-first-search

I am solving the problem in which I have to check whether a binary tree is BST or not?
I am getting wrong solution and hence some of my test cases are failing.
I am not able to find where am I wrong.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Definition for binary tree
 * class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) {
 *      val = x;
 *      left=null;
 *      right=null;
 *     }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    ArrayList<Integer> l=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public int isValidBST(TreeNode A) {

        inOrderUtil(A);
        for(int i=1;i<l.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.print(l.get(i)+" ");
            if(l.get(i)<l.get(i-1))
            return 0;            
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public void inOrderUtil(TreeNode root)
    {
        if(root==null)
        return;

        inOrderUtil(root.left);
        this.l.add((root.val));
        inOrderUtil(root.right);        
    }        
}
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of failed test cases?

Comment: input:11 3 2 4 1 3 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

Comment: Line 1 ( Corresponds to arg 1 ) : First number represents the number of integers in input line. Then follows serialized representation of the tree. The serialization of a binary tree follows a level order description of left and right child of nodes, where -1 signifies a NULL child.
    For example,
         1
        / \ 
       2    3
          /
        4
         \
          5
    will have representation as {1 2 3 -1 -1 4 -1 -1 5 -1 -1}
    The first integer on the line indicates the number of integers to follow in the serialized representation of the tree.

Comment: Actually, I am not able to understand the input. I have just solved it by taking care of all the test cases. But I might have missed something

Comment: Please post [mcve]. This should include test data (tree) and expected output

Comment: Sorry, From next time I will take care. By the way I have solved this problem , test cases were failing in case of duplicates. So,I corrected i<=l.size()